# Failed to parse plugin descriptor for maven:maven-nsis-plugin:2.1

Tags: java, plugins, maven, nsis

I am exploring the usage of nsis (newbie) in maven.

I have created the dependency in my pom.xml. It is downloaded successfully, but when I clean & compile my project, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for maven:maven-nsis-plugin:2.1
(C:\... \.m2\repository\maven\maven-nsis-plugin\2.1\maven-nsis-plugin-2.1.jar):
No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried to delete `\.m2\repository\maven\`, but it did not help. Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: Finally gave up and discovered Lauch4j, which is much better documented and integrated with Maven...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the codehaus plugin. You can find an operational example using it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595214/1282124

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you can using Maven 1.x version of the plugin with Maven 2/3.

- [maven nsis plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/nsis/) is a Maven 1.x plugin
- [nsis maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/index.html) is the Maven 2/3 plugin

Comment: I tried tons of tricks to make it work properly, but it never did. If you have an operational example, I think people would appreciate it...